# Javascript object manipulation with Jquery $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I doing wrong here ???

```
var menu = {
    menuset : {
        first  : false,
        second : false,
        third  : false
    },
    setMenus   : function (selected) {

        var menuCollection = this.menuset;

        $.each(menuCollection, function (key, element) {
            if (selected===key) {
                key=true;
            } else {
                key=false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I execute   "menu.setMenus(first)" I want it to set the object like this :

```
    menuset : {
        first  : true,
        second : false,
        third  : false
    }
```

should I be using something other than $.each() ??

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use each in this case. Your setMenus function could be like this: this.menuset[ selected ] = true; (assuming you did all the modifications proposed by Jayendra)

Comment: Luiz think of this as a menu where only one navigation item is "active" hence the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try -

```
var menu = {
    menuset : {
        'first'  : false,
        'second' : false,
        'third'  : false
    },
    setMenus   : function (selected) {

        var menuCollection = this.menuset;

        $.each(menuCollection, function (key, element) {
            if (selected === key) {
                menuCollection[key] = true;
            } else {
                menuCollection[key] = false;
            }
        });
    }
}

menu.setMenus('first');
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/nu9v2/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. `first` is a property of this.menuset, but you are passing it just as 
       `first`.
2. The first arg to the callback fn for `$.each` is an integer index, but you
       are passing in a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery

```
var menu = {
    menuset : {
        'first'  : false,
        'second' : false,
        'third'  : false
    },
    setMenus   : function (selected) {
        // set other values to false
        var keys = Object.keys(this.menuset);
        for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
            this.menuset[keys[i]] = false;
        }
        // set correct value to true
        this.menuset[selected] = true;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SFDKr/)

Comment: But if you set another menuset to true both will be `true`, i think the op's intent is only for ONE menuset to be true, hence the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> should I be using something other than $.each() ??

I think [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) would be better here:

```
setMenus: function (selected) {
   this.menuset = $.map(this.menuset, function(val, key) { return key == selected })
}
```